# email format and DNS verification in laravel, lumen php frameworks

Tags: laravel, lumen

**Emails samples as below**

abs.ss@gmail.com,example@yahoo.in,example@test.in,example@111.example.in

Email **format** and **DNS verification** in **Laravel, lumen** for **emails campaign** to decrease email bounce and **increase the Reputation** of the Sender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Solution #1**

I got it my solution over GitHub Library  https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator

[image]

1. **RFCValidation**: Standard RFC-like email validation.
2. **NoRFCWarningsValidation**: RFC-like validation that will fail when warnings* are found.
3. **DNSCheckValidation**: Will check if there are DNS records that signal that the server accepts emails. This does not entail that the
   email exists.

> **Solution #2**

This email validation checks if the **email address domain exists** or is configured to receive emails. It **gets all MX**, A and **AAAA DNS** records for the host, and then it will count email address as valid if **MX** records exist and its target is not empty or if A and/or **AAAA DNS** records exist.

https://minuteoflaravel.com/validation/laravel-email-validation-be-aware-of-how-you-validate/